# How to use an initial posterior for recursive / sequential updating in WinBUGS

Tags: bayesian, joint-distribution, posterior, bugs

I am using WinBUGS to estimate / update the parameters of a model.  The model is: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
D(T,B,a)&= B*(a_0+a_1T+a_2T^2+a_3T^3)+error(B,T,a)  \\
error &= \mathcal N(0, B^{0.5}a_4(a_0+a_1T+a_2T^2+a_3T^3))
\end{aligned}
$$
where $D$ is an observed response, $B$ and $T$ are observed input parameters and $a_i$s are non-observable model parameters.

To estimate the model parameters with the first set of data, I used non-informative normal priors for $a_i$'s.

My question is: **If I want to do sequential / recursive updating,** that is to use a set of observations $(D,B,T)$ to compute posterior distributions for the model parameters and then use these posteriors as priors to update model parameters given a new set of data $(D,B,T)$ (and so on), **can I directly use the posterior distributions that WinBUGS finds or should I instead care about the joint posterior distribution?**

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user21245, I took the liberty of formatting your question for greater clarity and readability. Please make sure it still says what you want it to.

Comment: Very good question!